robot_localization getting nan fusing odometry
I am trying to fuse odometry and imu data with the robot_localization for an omnidirectional robot. I always get the error:
Critical Error, NaNs were detected in the output state of the filter. This was likely due to poorly coniditioned process, noise, or sensor covariances.
enter code here

Now I reduced my problem just to fusing odometry but I still get the same error.
My setting for the robot_localization is:
    ekf_filter_node:
    ros__parameters:
        frequency: 30.0
        sensor_timeout: 0.1
        two_d_mode: true
        transform_time_offset: 0.0
        transform_timeout: 0.0
        print_diagnostics: true
        debug: true
        debug_out_file: /debug.txt
        permit_corrected_publication: false
        publish_acceleration: false
        publish_tf: false
        map_frame: map              
        odom_frame: odom            
        base_link_frame: base_link 
        world_frame: odom           
        odom0: odom
        odom0_config: [false, false, false, #x, y, z
                    false, false, false, #roll, pitch, yaw
                    true, true, false, #vx, vy, vz
                    false, false, true, #vroll, vpitch, vyaw
                    false, false, false] #ax, ay, az
        odom0_queue_size: 2
        odom0_differential: false
        odom0_relative: false
        odom0_pose_use_child_frame: false
        odom0_pose_rejection_threshold: 5.0
        odom0_twist_rejection_threshold: 1.0
        use_control: false
        stamped_control: false
        control_timeout: 0.2
        control_config: [true, true, false, false, false, true]
        acceleration_limits: [1.3, 1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.4]
        deceleration_limits: [1.3, 1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.5]
        acceleration_gains: [0.8, 0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9]
        deceleration_gains: [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
        process_noise_covariance: [0.05, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.05, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.06, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.03, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.03, 0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.06, 0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.025, 0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.025, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.04, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.01, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.01, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.02, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.01, 0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.01, 0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.015]
        initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9]

For the odom0_config i followed the recommendations in the documentation of robot_localization. The other settings I left at the default values.
The Odometry message looks like this:
    {
  "header": {
    "stamp": {
      "sec": 1723466141,
      "nsec": 468616259
    },
    "frame_id": "odom"
  },
  "child_frame_id": "base_link",
  "pose": {
    "pose": {
      "position": {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "z": 0
      },
      "orientation": {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "z": 0,
        "w": 1
      }
    },
    "covariance": [
      0.01,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0.01,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0.01,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0.01,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0.01,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0.01
    ]
  },
  "twist": {
    "twist": {
      "linear": {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "z": 0
      },
      "angular": {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "z": 0
      }
    },
    "covariance": [
      0.01,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0.01,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0.01,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0.01,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0.01,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0.01
    ]
  }
}

I set the covariances to a diagonal matrix with a constant value to not get an illconditioned matrix. As this was a problem mentioned in another post.
Below I have added the output of the debug text for the first predict/correct step where nan's occur.


Thanks for any help!
Edit:
You can find the full log file here.

With any sensor fusion package, I would advise always starting with a simple configuration and then adding complexity as needed.
Question: does this happen when the robot is static, or when it moves? Have you looked at the sensor data immediately leading up to the NaN values?
Your issue starts long before the output you pasted in the debug logs (also, I recommend not posting images - just paste the output in a code block). You can see that your X covariance has exploded already. If your odometry covariance is truly static, then there are two places I'd look:

Turn off the pose and twist rejection thresholds. Those are advanced parameters that should be used after you've characterized your sensors and state behaviour thoroughly. Off the top of my head, I think the most likely scenario is that your measurements are being rejected in some dimensions, leading to unbounded growth in the covariance in those dimensions.
I see you turned control off in your config above, but sometimes users paste configs that they modified after they last reported the issue. I would remove anything related to control from your config.
Finally, double-check that the time stamps on your sensor data are correct. If the filter thinks they are too old, it will ignore them.

EDIT after question update.
You posted an image, and I'd recommend linking to a Google drive text file or something. However, in the image, you can see that at the time you posted the debug data, the estimate error covariance is already broken (see Current estimate error covariance is:). Those values are going to get inverted, so you're going to see some awful things happening. You'd need to show data from earlier.
EDIT after second update.
If you look at the debug information, the issue occurs immediately. Your estimate error covariance is singular the very first time it gets printed:
[1e-09       1e-09       1e-09       1e-09       1e-09       1e-09       1e-09       1e-09       1e-09       1e-09       1e-09       1e-09       1e-09       1e-09       1e-09       
 6.3734e-322 2.2635e-313 -1.5139e+63 1e-09       1e-09       1e-09       1e-09       1e-09       1e-09       1e-09       1e-09       1e-09       1e-09       1e-09       1e-09       
 1e-09       2.1393e-321 1e-06       0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           9.2712e-310 0           
 0           0           0           1e-06       0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           9.2712e-310 0           
 9.2712e-310 0           0           0           1e-06       1.334e-322  0           0           0           0           0           0           0           9.2712e-310 0           
 0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           6.3734e-322 1e-09       1e-09       1e-09       1e-09       
 1e-09       1e-09       0           0           0           1e-09       0.01        0           0           0           0           0           4.645e+151  5.2856e+180 0           
 3.2829e-317 0           0           0           0           1.7888e+161 0           0.01        0           0           0           0           1e-09       1e-09       0           
 1e-09       1e-09       0           0           0           1e-09       0           0           1e-06       0           0           0           0           0           0           
 0           0.01        0           0           0           0           0           0           0           1e-06       0           0           0           0           0           
 0           0           0           0           0           5.2856e+180 0           0           0           0           1e-06       0           2.2386e-297 2.3281e+185 0           
 8.4045e-315 5.305e-313  0           0           0           1.0118e-320 0           0           0           0           0           0.01        0           0           0           
 0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0.05        0           0           
 0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0.06        0           
 0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           1e-06       ]

This is because something strange is happening when it gets loaded:
Initial estimate error covariance is:
(1.0000000000000000623e-09 1.0000000000000000623e-09 1.0000000000000000623e-09 1.0000000000000000623e-09 1.0000000000000000623e-09 1.0000000000000000623e-09 1.0000000000000000623e-09 1.0000000000000000623e-09 1.0000000000000000623e-09 1.0000000000000000623e-09 1.0000000000000000623e-09 1.0000000000000000623e-09 1.0000000000000000623e-09 1.0000000000000000623e-09 1.0000000000000000623e-09 )

But I used your config and that ^ doesn't happen for me. I see a full matrix in that inital printout. Which version of the EKF are you using (which ROS distro)? Did you modify the source? Are there possibly strange characters in your EKF config? Did you actually include the config that's being used? Double-check that your initial_estimate_error_covariance has exactly 15 values in the version on your machine.
The short version is that you are supplying the diagonal values for the initial_estimate_covariance, but for whatever reason, it's not seeing the value you specified in your parameters as the same as STATE_SIZE, which is 15. It drops to a second case where it then tries to load the entire matrix from that diagonal, but there's a bug with how that check is being done.
So if you can answer those ^ questions, I'd appreciate it. To get around the issue for now, you can either remove the initial_estimate_covariance parameter entirely in your config, or provide the full matrix.

Yes this happens when the robot is static. I did some experiments and the behavior is not deterministic. Sometimes even the first predict/correct iteration leads to NaN's. The measurment leading up to the error were all 0
I did not get this problem if I was just fusing the yaw rate. So i think it must be related to the linear velocities.
Regarding your advice:

Turning of the rejection thresholds did not make a difference
Yes I made sure that the control is turned off
Ho would I do that? Wouldn't I see that in the logs that measurements got rejected?


Regarding the image,  I reached the character limit of my question so this was the only way of showing the full predict/correct step

Updated the answer. I recommend posting a longer debug log somewhere.

Updated the question with a link to the full logfile on a googledrive. Thanks for the advice.

I still don't see how it's ending up loading the covariance incorrectly for you (the param works well for me), but I fixed the bug that would have at least caused the filter to yell at you instead of running:
https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/pull/909
